# Is it possible to extend an Interpolator?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm trying to extend a `Vector2DFieldInterpolator` in order to make a smooth arc animation given three points (start, end, and a point inbetween).

I've gotten it to work by setting the `key` and `keyValue` fields on a regular `Vector2DFieldInterpolator`, but now I wanted to put it all into one component so it can be easily reused.

Here is a minimum viable example of what I have right now:

Example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component name="ArcInterpolatorExample" extends="Scene" >
  <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/Example.brs"/>
  <children>
    <Rectangle id = "animateMe" height = "20" width = "20" color="#ffff00ff" 
      translation="[250,250]"/>
    <Label id="labelA" text="A" translation="[250,250]"/>
    <Label id="labelB" text="B" translation="[125,250]"/>
    <Label id="labelC" text="C" translation="[75,180]"/>
    <Animation 
      id="animate" 
      easeFunction="linear"
      duration="10">
        <ArcInterpolator 
          id="arcInterpol" 
          start="[250,250]" 
          middle="[125,250]" 
          end="[75,180]" 
          fieldToInterp="animateMe.translation"
        />
    </Animation>
  </children>
</component>
```

Example.brs:

```
sub init()
    m.arcAnimator = m.top.findNode("animate")
    m.arcAnimator.control = "start"
end sub
```

ArcInterpolator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component name="ArcInterpolator" extends="Vector2DFieldInterpolator">
    <interface>
        <field id="start" type="vector2d" onChange="onCoordinateSet"/>
        <field id="middle" type="vector2d" onChange="onCoordinateSet"/>
        <field id="end" type="vector2d" onChange="onCoordinateSet"/>
    </interface>
    <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/ArcInterpolator.brs"/>
</component>
```

ArcInterpolator.brs

```
sub init()
  m.pi = 3.1415927
end sub

sub onCoordinateSet()
    ' check that no two points are the same
    if (m.top.start[0] = m.top.middle[0] and m.top.start[1] = m.top.middle[1]) or (m.top.start[0] = m.top.end[0] and m.top.start[1] = m.top.end[1]) or (m.top.middle[0] = m.top.end[0] and m.top.middle[1] = m.top.end[1]) then
        return
    else
        setValues()
    end if
end sub

sub setValues()
    startpoint = m.top.start
    midpoint = m.top.middle
    endpoint = m.top.end
    numOfPoints = 11

    dim keys[numOfPoints-1]
    dim values[numOfPoints-1]
    keys[0] = 0.0
    keys[numOfPoints-1] = 1.0
    values[0] = startpoint
    values[numOfPoints-1] = endpoint

    ' a bunch of calculation is done here and keys and values are set

    m.top.key = keys
    m.top.keyValue = values
end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that YES, it is possible to extend an interpolator but that I was going about this the wrong way. There's a field on the interpolator called `fraction` which is updated during the course of the animation. There is also a field called `fieldToInterp` which describes the node and field to change.

In order to write your own interpolator, you need to find the node and field described by `fieldToInterp` and store it in `m` and then observe `fraction` and update that node's field according to what the fraction is. Here's what this ends up looking like:

ArcInterpolator.brs:

```
sub init()
  m.pi = 3.1415927
  m.top.observeField("fraction", "calculateValue")
  m.top.observeField("fieldToInterp", "findNodeToMove")
end sub

sub findNodeToMove(event as object)
    nodeAndField = event.getData()
    if right(nodeAndField, 12) <> ".translation" then return
    length = len(nodeAndField)
    nodeName = left(nodeAndField, length - 12)

    currentNode = m.top
    while currentNode.getParent() <> invalid
        currentNode = currentNode.getParent()
        node = currentNode.findNode(nodeName)
        if node <> invalid
            m.nodeToMove = node
            exit while
        end if
    end while
end sub

sub onCoordinateSet()
    ' check that no two points are the same
    if (m.top.start[0] = m.top.middle[0] and m.top.start[1] = m.top.middle[1]) or (m.top.start[0] = m.top.end[0] and m.top.start[1] = m.top.end[1]) or (m.top.middle[0] = m.top.end[0] and m.top.middle[1] = m.top.end[1]) then
        return
    else
        setValues()
    end if
end sub

sub setValues()
    ' do some math to set the center of the circle, total angle, start angle etc.
end sub

sub calculateValue(event as object)    
    fraction = event.getData()
    angle = fraction * m.totalAngle + m.startAngle
    dim position[1]
    position[0] = m.center[0] + m.radius * cos(angle)
    position[1] = m.center[1] + m.radius * sin(angle)
    m.nodeToMove.translation = position
end sub
```